# newer Interbase download cannot create a database

Tags: interbase

I replaced my laptop, and tried to install Interbase for use with Delphi

I went into Ibconsole and am unable to create, import, or add
a database. I have several .ib files that work fine on an
older pc, but when I try to add the ib file I get the same
error: Internal gds software consistency check (next transaction
older than oldest active transaction (266), file:pag.c line: 1365)

So I now have a server running, but it has no databases.
Ibserver manager shows the server (gds_db) is running.

How do I get past the ...next transaction older...
Thank you.